# Django admin site customization

Tags: python, django

My models:

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='paymenttype', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='gradelevel', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Discount_Type = models.ForeignKey(Discount,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Remarks = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Student_Users}  {0.Education_Levels}'
        return suser.format(self)
```

what i want to search:

```
class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Students_Enrollment_Records}    {0.Subject_Section_Teacher}'
        return suser.format(self)
```

Image:

[image]

Can i search here if i select what ever i want in section, my search will appear below?

Do you guys have an idea or better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourappname.models import Question 

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['question_text'] # select which field you want to search
    list_filter = ['Remarks']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/

[image]